# sending xml from c# to php

Tags: c#, php

My C# CODE looks like this :

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string SayHello(int integer ,  string str , bool boolean)
        {

            string xml = str;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            XmlNode myNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Request/SelectedReportType");
            myNode.InnerText = "Defaulted";
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

            doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);

            return doc.OuterXml;

        }
    }
}
```

and my php code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$class1 = new DOTNET("Sample,"
                    ."Version=1.0.0.0,"
                    ."Culture=neutral,"
                    ."PublicKeyToken=9177A3c122DAAC6c"
                    ,"Sample.Class1");
$string = ($class1->SayHello

(1,"<Request><SelectedReportType>TRANSACTIONS</SelectedReportType><ReportLevel>GLOBAL_ISSUER</ReportLevel><ReportDepth>1</ReportDepth><SearchString>ByCusip</

SearchString><SelectedReportScope>PORTFOLIO</SelectedReportScope><MaxReturn>0</MaxReturn><IsExactMatch>false</IsExactMatch></Request>",True));

echo $string;
//print_r(simplexml_import_dom($string)); 
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Basically i am try to use c# dll in php script and was trying a prototype demo .when i try to echo the value of $string in php it displays me the output as `DefaultedGLOBAL_ISSUER1ByCusipPORTFOLIO0false`
rather than

```
<Request><SelectedReportType>defaulted</SelectedReportType><ReportLevel>GLOBAL_ISSUER</ReportLevel><ReportDepth>1</ReportDepth><SearchString>ByCusip</SearchString><SelectedReportScope>PORTFOLIO</SelectedReportScope><MaxReturn>0</MaxReturn><IsExactMatch>false</IsExactMatch></Request>
```

since i am returning a string from c# which i created from a xmldocument .i expect the xml document string to passed to php rather just the elements of the xml.

Can someone help me out to know as what can be the issue

Comment: look at the source of the page, you are getting the XML but the browser is trying to display it as HTML, so you are only seeing the text, after all you are echoing inside an html page

Comment: ok ,thanks . that answer's my query